# Django model for real estate

Tags: python, database, django

I have built a real estate management system with Django. I want to know if my design database was wrong. Please let me know how to improve it.

Should I make the models use more than two tables (classes)?

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profiles', default='logo.png')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11, default='')
    bio = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    city = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='erbil')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='')
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user}'


class Listing(models.Model):
    objects = ListingManager()

    company = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, default='', blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=city_choices, default='lodon')
    estate_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=estate_choices, default=house)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    rent_sale = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=rent_sale_choice, default=sale)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    bedrooms = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    bathrooms = models.DecimalField(max_digits=2, decimal_places=1)
    garage = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    sqft = models.IntegerField()
    sold =  models.BooleanField(default=False)
    sold_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now,blank=True)
    photo_main = models.ImageField(upload_to='listings_main')
    photo_1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='listings_1', blank=True)
    photo_2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='listings_1', blank=True)
    photo_3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='listings_1', blank=True)
    photo_4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='listings_1', blank=True)
    photo_5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='listings_1', blank=True)
    photo_6 = models.ImageField(upload_to='listings_1', blank=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    list_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    unless = models.CharField(default='', max_length=20)
```

Answer (score 3):

As a rule of thumb in programming, "there are only four numbers": zero, one, two, and "many".  You have seven photo fields, which means that you should just treat that as "many".  Not only is that an unfortunate artificial limitation (someday there will be a listing with eight photos, and you won't be able to accommodate it easily), it's also a pain to write code that uses your schema (you either have to copy-and-paste code six times, or use variably-named identifiers).

What you want is a separate table for photos, to support a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: The rule I use is "a few" and "a lot" instead of two and many. But this is an excellent point!

Comment: class Listing(models.Model):
    .
    .
    .
    .
    images = models.OneTwoManyField(Image)

class Image(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='listings') , how is it? thanks  for your suggestions